# Counting multiple occurrences of words in text vector in R

Tags: r, string

I have the following:

```
text <- c('I am a human','It is an animal and not a human, I am a human','Cant think of something else to write','and and is am')
words <- c('and','am','is')
```

I want to count the sum of the occurrences of these words in the text. So the output should be the following:

```
[1] 1 3 0 4
```

I am using the following code which it is clearly not the most elegant:

```
TotalCount <- vector(mode='integer',length = 4)
for (ii in 1:4){
    for(jj in 1:3){
          wordCount <- str_count(text[ii],words[jj])
          TotalCount[ii] <- wordCount + TotalCount[ii]
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient,elegand way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `str_count` function from `stringr` library.

```
library(stringr)
text <- c('I am a human','It is an animal and not a human, I am a human','Cant think of something else to write','and and is am')
words <- c('and','am','is')
str_count(text, paste(words, collapse="|"))
# [1] 1 3 0 4
```

or

```
str_count(text, paste0(c("\\b("),paste(words,collapse="|"),c(")\\b")))
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. I gave a simple example. Trying to put it my real data the code had a problem to run it when there was a words like 'bull***' or 'bull----'. How can i overpass that?

Comment: if you don't want to count the above then use lookarounds. `str_count(text, paste0(c("(?<!\\S)("),paste(words,collapse="|"),c(")(?!\\S)")))`

Comment: And if i want to count them ?

Comment: `str_count` do counting.

Comment: if you replace the words vector with : words <- c('and','am','is','bull*****') there is Syntax error in str_count_regex.